# Simple way to import javadoc in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

is there a simple way to add the javadoc+sources of a library in eclipse without having to add both references in the JAR properties manually?

It seems to me there could be some kind of automatic configuration considering the file names or file locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find yourself constantly using the same JAR files the recommendation I've received is to create a base "Skeleton Directory". In Eclipse I've done this by creating a single project title "Skeleton" with no classes but all the JAR files I use normally. I then duplicate this project and rename it to use for each new project. Saves a lot of time. Also recommend removing any unneeded JAR files before uploading anywhere

If you are looking to do just the Javadoc you can do it via URL

"Right Click the JAR file in Project Explorer -> Properties -> From the left pane choose Javadoc Location -> enter the URL of your jar documentation.

Generally you can Google for: javadoc lib-name and then pickup the URL of the first site suggested by Google - going up a level."

(Source: https://superuser.com/questions/167458/how-to-add-javadocs-to-eclipse)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well I'd name that a "template" rather than a skeleton, but it seems to be a good enough solution for me and it does fit the season :) Another solution I just tried is to configure the template project and import it as dependency. When using external libraries Eclipse will propose to import them from the template project, and  so they come with the sources/docs already linked.